# Дни в промежутке между двумя датами

Tags: mysql

Как можно выбрать все дни (и вставить их в пустую таблицу) в промежутке между двумя датами?

Comment: если я верно понял, то вы хотите создать список дней между 2х дат, да?

Comment: да, именно так

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, как пример ( данные пишутся во временную таблицу, процедура самоудаляется ):

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );

  delimiter //;
  CREATE PROCEDURE `date_between` ( dfrom DATE, dto DATE )
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE curr DATE;
    SET curr = dfrom;
    WHILE ( curr <  dto ) DO 
      INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( NULL, curr );
      SET curr = curr + INTERVAL 1 day;
    END WHILE;
  END//;
  delimiter ;
  call date_between('2011-09-01', '2011-12-31');

  DROP PROCEDURE `date_between`;

  SELECT * FROM `test`;
```

Answer (score 1):

используй команду between

Comment: Забыл написать: таблица есть, но она пустая. Не знаю как ее заполнить. А после можно будет уже и BETWEEN применить. (Поля таблицы, к примеру, id, dates).

Comment: ее очень просто заполнять, сначало создай ее, создай поля, ну и можешь ее заполнять, либо вручную, либо у тебя на php есть форма для нее

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `created` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2010-09-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2010-10-01','%Y-%m-%d')
```

Если не сработает, то тогда просто строки сравнивайте. но это бред